# Windows Server 2003 SBS cannot download files

Tags: windows-server-2003, internet-explorer, windows-sbs-2003

I have an extremely bizarre issue on one of SBS2003 servers, belonging to my client. Server cannot access *some* URLs. I can access simple sites, such as google, but every time I'm trying to go to msn.com, or mozypro.com the site will timeout.

With that said, server is responsive, it will access network, open files. Other computers on the same network will access all internet URLs fine.

In attempt to fix the issue, I did following things:

- uninstalled IE enchanced security
- tried using Chrome instead of IE
- disabled firewall
- made sure there is no IP blocks
- plugged in a separate USB ethernet card to rule out ethernet issue

any more ideas?..

Comment: Please make sure you turn IE Enhanced Security back on and, talk to your client about why they should not browse the Internet from their primary domain controller!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turns to be not in the server itself. DSL router was running firmware which somehow messed up the traffic going from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that DNS is configured and working properly?

Comment: yes, dns is working and resolving the domain names properly